# Populating combobox from app settings

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am attempting to fill a combobox with name and values from a appsettings file.  Once a name is selected from the combobox I would like to have the value sent to a textbox below. I guess the part I am confused about is how to determine which is selected and display that value.

My goal would be to select Name "cmd" from combobox and have the value of path/to/cmd.exe into textbox below.

```
       public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] names = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys;
            NameValueCollection appStgs = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

            for (int i = 0; i < appStgs.Count; i++)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(names[i]);                               
            }

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] names = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys;
            NameValueCollection appStgs = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
            for (int i = 0; i < appStgs.Count; i++)
            {
              textBox3.Text = appStgs[comboBox1.Text];

            }


        }
```

Comment: First, is this WinForms or WPF project? Second, parts of the code do not make sense. What is the reason for checking `SelectedIndex` like that (==1 and ==2)? The only hard-coded value to check `SelectedIndex` against should be -1.

Comment: My bad about not having the first -1, I did have it in originally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox3.Text = appStgs[comboBox1.Text];
}
```

Comment: So currently I would be limited to how many items can be added? How could I go about this dynamically?
If I was to have more options in appsettings then I have defined in code for SelectedIndex ==

Comment: @user2190928 Not sure I understand the question. My code is just one line, and `SelectedIndex` is not even used. This is the way to go about it.

Comment: I understand now. I was thinking I stilled needed the If.